# preg_replace & regular expression help

Tags: php, regex

A friend helped us with this line of code a while back, and I'm trying to get it to work for this:

```
$curPageUrl = "http://www.site.com/index.php?sort=a";
$currentPage = preg_replace("/&sort=\w+/", "", $curPageUrl);
echo $currentPage; // http://www.site.com/index.php?sort=f?sort=a?sort=z
```

For example, `$curPageUrl` gets the clients page they are on and then it passes it through this.

Basically, we want `$currentPage` to strip off:

```
?sort=a
?sort=f
?sort=z
```

from the `$curPageUrl`

I hope my example helped.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use e.g. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: What @Daniel said. Additionally you'll have a problem in that the first query parameter does not have a `&` in front, but a `?` (in your example they all have `?`s, but that is not true. It's `.../index.php?param1=x&param2=y&...`)

Comment: We have other get variables, we want to keep these and replace existing sorts if they are changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/(\?|\&)sort=\w+/", "", $curPageUrl);
```

It will accept '&' or '?'.

Comment: Thats even better than what I was after. Thank you.

Comment: It will change `http://www.site.com/index.php?sort=a&foo=bar` to `http://www.site.com/index.php&foo=bar` which lacks the required `?`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$tests = array(
    "http://www.site.com/index.php",
    "http://www.site.com/index.php?sort=a",
    "http://www.site.com/index.php?foo=bar&sort=a",
    "http://www.site.com/index.php?foo=bar&sort=a&bla=baz",
    "http://www.site.com/index.php?sort=a&bla=baz"
);
foreach($tests as $test) {
    echo preg_replace(
        array('@\?sort=[^&]*@', '@&sort=[^&]*@'),
        array('?', ''),
        $test
    );
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace("/\?sort=\w+/", "", $curPageUrl);`